# PHP Sdk - Facebook Login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have searched on google the latest tutorial for the facebook login but the last one I could find was early 2014 or late 2013. I realise that facebook updated in aprill 2014 to a new way of facebook login and there are no new tutorials for it. Are there any tutorials you can give me the link too or help me get started in adding facebook login to my website? Also is php the easiest way out of php and java script? I have downloaded the newest php sdk but I have no idea where to start without a tutorial I can also read the docs on developers facebook but they all just explain little parts. None of the docs go into how you can add the facebook login to your website and yes I have created my app

Comment: Facebook APIs are the worst documented stuff for programmars. I always get headache with them

Comment: You can use http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/; i don't know how difficult it would be for you to implement it, but it's got ton of examples and documentation.

Comment: I would have to agree that API's are usually not documented very well but the first page from the docs has a basic tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

Comment: I was hoping for a easier tutorial but  Ill try this thanks!

Comment: the facebook docs are VERY good already. they were only bad a very long time ago. use the javascript sdk for login (and most other things), not the php sdk.

Comment: What are the reasons you would use javascript sdk not php sdk?